# Android Passing data to intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities in my android application, and i am trying to get user input data from the first activity and pass it to the third activity while at the same time I launch the second activity which also gets the user input data and will also pass the data to the third activity. any ideas on how i should go about this?

Comment: Can you explain in a better way?

Comment: 3 activities.....activity 1 takes data to 3rd activity when user clicks button and launches activity 2 sametime ...

Comment: And why would you want to do that? Activity 1 is A, Activity 2 is B, 3 is C. Pass the parameter to B. When you go to C, get the retrieved parameter and pass it to C...?

Comment: do you fixed ?.

Comment: You can't pass data to some 3rd Activity, then start a 2nd activity and just expect that data to be sitting in the 3rd Activity whenever you want to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

The Way of passing data from Intent is shown below, try passing data same way from `ActivityOne -> ActvityTwo -> ActivityThree.`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key_from_one", some_value_from_one);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("some_key_from_one");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```